# Windows - redirect domain request to localhost without modifying etc/hosts

Tags: c++, windows, redirect, dns, hosts

I need programmaticaly (C++) add some kind of dns-resolving rule, to redirect requests of specific domain to localhost.
Are there any methods to do so without modyfing etc/hosts file on Windows?

Comment: Only your own program, or also others? Because any decent Internet Security Suite *will* flag your application as spyware when you do that to other applications. The one exception might be if you set up a local DNS proxy.

Comment: For any software running. Assume, that there is no Internet Security Suite or it is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

You install a local DNS server to your machine (for example: BIND). Then you change the IP settings on your machine to use your own local DNS server (127.0.0.1) instead of your normal DNS servers. Then you create a new domain (with the name of the DNS name to be redirected) on your local DNS server, and include an address record in the zone file of that domain, specifying the desired IP address (127.0.0.1). There is one more step that might be neccessary: if your machine cannot reach the Internet DNS servers directly, only through the normal DNS servers, you have to configure DNS request forwarding into your local DNS server, so that every domain request would be forwarded to the original DNS servers.

Comment: Yeah, there are ways to do that with some additional software. The main point of my question is to do it inside c++ code, without any additional software.